# ffmpeg merge video with 2 audio files

Tags: ffmpeg, video, audio

What I'm trying to accomplish is the following:
I want to use `ffmpeg` (preferably a single command) to combine a video (`video.mp4`) file with an audio file (`audio.mp3`) and have some background music (`music.mp3`) playing.
The output should end after the length of `audio.mp3` (or even better after the end of `audio.mp3` + 5 seconds). So music and video are allowed to be cut.

All separate tasks work in a way but putting everything together just doesn't work.

My approach (with some extras like fading in video and audio volume control):

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -i audio.mp3 -i music.mp3 -vf "fade=t=in:st=0:d=5" -filter_complex
"[1:a]volume=1[audio]; [2:a]volume=0.25[music];
[audio][music]amix=inputs=2[mix]"
-map 0:v -map "[mix]" -c:v h264 -c:a aac -shortest output.mp4
```

That works but the output is not cut after the the duration of the shortest file (which is always the `audio.mp3`)

**Second question:**
Is it possible to refine that command so `video.mp4` and `music.mp3` don't need to be very long but are looped until the end of `audio.mp3` + 5s?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I managed to do the audio part at least (after that I combine the audio track with the video):

```
ffmpeg -f lavfi -t 5 -i anullsrc=channel_layout=stereo:sample_rate=192000 -i file1.mp3 -filter_complex "[1:a][0:a]concat=n=2:v=0:a=1[audio_silence],amovie=file2.mp3:loop=0,asetpts=N/SR/TB,volume=0.1[music];[audio_silence][music]amix=duration=shortest,volume=1" out.mp3
```

But one thing is not quite as expected: The audio quality go really bad. There is hissing and some higher frequency noice ... i tried some low pass filtering but doesn't seem to help. Any ideas on that topic? I think I'll open another question for that.

Cheers